# design patterns scenario base learning

Tags: design-patterns

Do you know any resource/s that teaches design patterns by scenario.

Ex : One day x person needs a converting A/C tool between different country resources.....

Answer : Adapter Pattern .. because....

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In a language agnostic point of view, you should buy definitely this (easy to learn through examples): 
[http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

or Refactoring To Patterns for a more cause-and-effect approach: 
[http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Patterns-Joshua-Kerievsky/dp/0321213351](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351)

Comment: Head First Design Patterns (the first link) does *exactly* what the OP requests.

Comment: I should have linked the Refactoring to Patterns too.  Good job catching that one!

Answer (score 2):

[Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), Gang of Four.

Comment: I need an online resource -  i need just examples. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it is THE bible, but not the ideal book for a design patterns 101, from my point of view... (but of course a musthave for some deep knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

Along with Head-First-Design-Patterns and GoF Design Patterns. I suggest This list of books below:

- **Refactoring To Patterns** by *Joshua Kerievsky*
- **Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code**
     by *Martin Fowler, Kent Beck (Contributor), John Brant (Contributor), William
     Opdyke, don Roberts*
- **C# 3.0 Design Patterns** by *Judith Bishop*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Java-Patterns-Stephen-Stelting/dp/0130935387](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130935387)
If you need an online info:
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns, http://www.oodesign.com/

Answer (score 0):

Get the book from this guy. He explains 23 design patterns in under 100 pages and with nice simple examples.

Link: [Design Patterns in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008ZT9MOI)

And after you have read this for first time get this cheat-sheet in order to help you when you revisit the topic (almost in every project you make.

Link: [Design Patterns Quick Reference](http://www.mcdonaldland.info/2007/11/28/40/)